# sticky rows : fetching some rows always on top of list in postgresql

Tags: php, mysql, database, postgresql

Im fetching records from a table, say countries, I always need few rows on top(in first of result set)

---

ID     country

```
--------------------------
1      China
2      Japan
3      Taiwan
4      USA
5      Germany
6      Brazil
7      India
--------------------------
```

I want to keep Japan and China in the list top and then sort the rest

so the result set always should be

```
----------------------
Japan
China
next country
next country
next country
next country
----------------------
```

is there any way to do this using CTE or any other way that is right for this requirement?

Im using PostgreSQL 9.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pick those two countries out then add rest of them, something like:

```
select * from table 
  where country ='China' or country = 'Japan' 
union select * from table;
```

`union` already remove the duplicated rows for you.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I use this order by technique in mysql but should work in postgresql just as well.

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY FIELD(country, 'Japan', 'China') DESC;
```

One oddity or illogical bit at least in mysql is the query above will list China then Japan then all the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this objective using following query:

```
select your_column_list, 
(CASE country WHEN 'Japan' THEN 0 WHEN 'China' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) AS nu 
from your_table_name
ORDER BY nu ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends where is kept the information of the sticky countries.

If this information is kept directly in the country table, since true  > false you can just `ORDER BY is_sticky DESC, country_name ASC`

If this information is filled by the user and you know the country_id, then you can leverage the use of VALUES to keep the wanted countries on top list:

`SELECT
  label
FROM
  country
  LEFT JOIN (VALUES (3), (4)) ontop (label_id) USING (label_id)
ORDER BY
  ontop.label_id IS NOT NULL DESC,
  label ASC`

Of course you could JOIN directly on the country name but that is slower.